# SQL Find next missing number in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL table which contains a column of type Int. The values of this column are not in any particular order. The data basically looks like this: 1, 2, 10, 25, 97, 98, 105, 56999. How would I get the next missing number in that column? In this case the next missing number would be 3.

I'm only wanting one number; not all of them. All of them would take too long. I just need one at a time. I've seen other examples on this website pertaining to this issue but they all seem to involve getting all available numbers instead of just a single one.

Comment: why 3 and not 4?

Comment: How `3` is the missing number? What is the logic behind that? Why not `4` or `5` or `11` ?

Comment: 3 is simply the first missing number. I'm going to get the first missing number and use it to insert a record. The next time I run the query it will return 4 as 3 was just inserted.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, Oracle, ???

Comment: @Nick My apologies. I am using MS SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CTE` to generate a lagged version of your column, and then check whether the values are sequential, outputting the minimum value which is not:

```
with cte as (
  select col, lag(col) over (order by col) as lastcol
  from test
)
select MIN(lastcol) + 1
from cte
where col != lastcol + 1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4e6bbc73a09a9fd1b7b10eac2df0073d)

Comment: @Rhendar no worries - both answers will solve your problem equally well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
select t.col + 1
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.col = t.col + 1
                 )
order by t.col asc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

You can also use `lead()`:

```
select min(col + 1)
from (select t.*, lead(col) over (order by col) as next_col
      from t
     ) t
where next_col is null or next_col <> col + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

the first thing that comes to mind:

if x is the name of your column and test is the name of your table:

```
with cte as (
    select x, dense_rank() over(order by x) rnk
    from test
)
select min(rnk)
from cte
where x > rnk;
```